# Local python/django script can't access remote database

Tags: django, apache, virtualization, vagrant, iptables

I am trying to access my remote PostgreSQL database from my local virtual machine (built with VirtualBox). I know the database works perfectly fine on the remote server.  The error I get from my local script is:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "314.15.926.53" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here's what I have done so far on the remote server (which is Ubuntu/Apache):

```
- Added "host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  md5" to the bottom of "/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf"
- Set listen_address = '*' in `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf`
- Ran from the command line: 
    - "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d 314.15.926.53  --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"
    - "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 314.15.926.53 --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"
- Restarted postgres and apache
```

And I still get the same timeout error. Can someone help point me in the right direction as to what to do next? Or what the potential cause may be?

Comment: Are you running vagrant?

Comment: Yes I am running vagrant

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Ubuntu...

Comment: So you're running vagrant using an ubuntu box on ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not positive if I'm understanding you correctly, but yes I am using vagrant to user my virtual machine, which is on VirtualBox, and I am using the Ubuntu lucid 64 box (can be found at... http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid64.box)

Comment: No, I'm asking what is your native OS?

Comment: From within the guest, try to do this `nc -vz 314.15.926.53 5432` see if you can make a TCP connection to the DB host first. This is to confirm that there is a route to 314.15.926.53.

Comment: @jball037 If you can't ping the same IP either, that means the guest has no route to `174.36.220.26`, networking is not configured properly. You have to provide the big picture of how these are connected.